# Inverse of a peculiar block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, block-matrices

I'd like to find the inverse of a certain 2x2 block matrix. Since its structure is peculiar, the usual inverse formula cannot be applied. However, for the same reason, I think there is a way to elegantly compute it.
Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix, I am interested in computing the inverse of

$$M =\begin{bmatrix}
I \quad A^T\\
A \quad 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

with $I$ the identity matrix of size $m$ and 0 the null square matrix of size $n$. Thus, is there a simple way of computing $M^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [block matrix inverse formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) states that

$\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\
    \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
     \mathbf{A}^{-1} + \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
      -\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1} \\
    -\left(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{CA}^{-1} &
       \left(\mathbf{D} - \mathbf{CA}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix}$

provided that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$ are both invertible.

Applying that formula yields

$$\begin{bmatrix}I & A^T \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} I - A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A & A^T(AA^T)^{-1}\\ (AA^T)^{-1}A& -(AA^T)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

provided that $AA^T$ is invertible.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for catching that typo.